# SpringSecurity BasicAuthenticationFilter with custom AuthenticationManager

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth, spring-security-oauth2

For the BasicAuthenticationFilter, I am trying to inject my own AuthenticationManager.
But when I debug the Startup, I always find out that the Class *BasicAuthenticationFilter.java* is not using my AuthenticationManager.

How can I pass it into the BasicAuthenticationFilter ?

I am using SpringBoot 2.1.0 and Spring-Security-Oauth2 2.0.1

**AuthorizationConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationConfiguration extends 
AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("passwordEncoder")
private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(passwordEncoder.encode("SECRET"));
    clients
    .inMemory()
    .withClient("clientapp")
    .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials")
    .authorities("USER")
    .scopes("read", "write")
    .secret(passwordEncoder.encode("SECRET"));

}

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
    security.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()");
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
    endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
}
}
```

**WebSecurityConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

@Override
@Bean(name = BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
@Primary
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManager();
}


@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(16); 
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring()
    .antMatchers(ResourceConfiguration.TEST_PATHS);
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuth = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    daoAuth.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuth);
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I used the wrong package in my build.gradle

To solve the issue I added the following package:

**build.gradle**

```
implementation("org.springframework.security.oauth.boot:spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure:${springBootVersion}")
```

Answer (score 0):

In your WebSecurityConfiguration, authenticationManagerBean() should return your own AuthenticationManager bean instance, not super.authenticationManager()?

Comment: No I override the configure() method with my settings

Answer (score 0):

With your given configuration, you will actually get two instances of `BasicAuthenticationFilter`. And both should get your `AuthenticationManager` just fine. For one of them, though, it is a parent `AuthenticationManager`, meaning you should also check the `authenticationManager.parent` property in your debugger.

Your `AuthenticationManager`, as is, though, may have a couple of issues.

Spring Security OAuth will create two filter chains (and subsequently two `BasicAuthenticationFilter`s, two `AuthenticationManager`s); one for OAuth endpoints, like `/oauth/token`, and another for everything else.

The filter chain created for OAuth endpoints takes the `UserDetailsService` you specified via `ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer` and applies it to the `AuthenticationManager` you specified.

If I take your configuration and place it into my IDE and then do:

`curl --user clientapp:SECRET localhost:8080/oauth/token -dgrant_type=client_credentials`

Then it will come back with a token just fine.

However, it doesn't apply those clients to the `AuthenticationManager` for the rest of the requests. The reason for this is because, with Authorization Servers, there are often two different kinds of users: clients and end users. The clients need to use the OAuth API while users just need to use the web application (login, etc.).

That means if you try and do:

`curl --user clientapp:SECRET localhost:8080`

It won't work. The set of users hasn't been applied to that filter chain.

If you have non-OAuth2 endpoints, then you'll need to specify a set of users yourself in a `UserDetailsService`. Without this, when you try and hit these endpoints with basic, there are no users for it to look up.

Further, the default `AuthenticationManager` will pick up your `PasswordEncoder` automatically. So instead of your `WebSecurityConfiguration#configure` method, you could do:

```
@Bean
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    return new InMemoryUserDetailsService(User
        .withUsername("user")
        .password(passwordEncoder().encode("password"))
        .role("USER")
        .build());
}
```

(It's still okay for you to customize the `AuthenticationManager`, too, if you need to do something more sophisticated.)

Trying this with your posted application (again changing out the `configure` method in `WebSecurityConfiguration` for the above), I'm able to also do:

```
curl --user user:password localhost:8080
```

Comment: Unfortunately  curl --user clientapp:SECRET localhost:8080  doesn't work